# Keep a Sharepoint List updated with User Profile changes

Tags: list, custom-list, user-profile-service

Here is a run-down on what I am hoping to achieve on Sharepoint 2013:

- We need to create a Sharepoint List of users. This list is a sub-set
  of users - only from certain departments, for example.
- We will be adding columns to this list that are specific to the
  project we are working on. eg: 'Has been inducted to project',
  'Project Role', 'Current Task', etc.
- Updates to user info in AD via the User Profile Service (new user,
  disabled user, department, etc.) would be reflected in the list. eg:
  New user gets added to the list.

I'm hoping for some direction on the best way of doing this, if it is even possible?

Many thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Is it SharePoint Online (Office 365) or On Premises? If it's on premises, a timer job can be built that reads all user profiles and updates the list.

However if it's Office 365, the options are limited. One of the ways is  -

Develop a Site Workflow that uses a REST call to fetch all site users, loops through site users, gets user profile info for these users, updates the list. The gotcha here is all site users doesn't mean all users, its all users who have visited the site.

Comment: On premises server, so a timer job sounds promising. Do updates/additions made in AD get reflected in the User Profile Change tables?

Comment: Updates in AD get synchronized to SharePoint User Profiles as part of the User Profile Synchronisation process. Please ensure that User Profile Sync is properly enabled and is working on your farm.

Comment: Yes, the User Profile Sync is working nicely. I am wanting to capture the changes made in AD so I can apply them to my Custom List.
I know the User Profile Change tables store changes to User Profiles, but my question is: "Does it only store changes made to profiles from within Sharepoint, or does it also include the changes from AD as well?"

Comment: User Profile Synchronisation synchronizes profile details from Active Directory to SharePoint users. So, yes, any change made in Active Directory will reflect in SharePoint Profiles. Refer to  [Plan user profiles in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721054.aspx) and [Overview of profile synchronization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg188041.aspx) for more details on User Profile Sync.

Comment: "Does it only store changes made to profiles from within Sharepoint, or does it also include the changes from AD as well? - Changes made to profiles within SharePoint are updated immediately from the edit profile page itself.  Changes from AD are "Synchronised" using the USer Profile Synchronisation.

Comment: Thanks JJJ, but you have mis-understood my question. I am well aware of the way changes in AD are synchronised to SharePoint Profiles. My question is in relation to the User Profile Change Service - if a user updates their profile information within SharePoint, the change is also logged here. My question is: are updates made in AD logged here also?